# How can you alias, or otherwise override, a scope and call the original?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scopes

A Spree addon adds a scope. Let's say:

```
class Product
  scope :in_sale, -> { where(in_sale: true) }
end
```

Note that the [actual scope](https://github.com/ronzalo/spree_sales/blob/master/app/models/spree/product_decorator.rb#L13) is slightly more complex.

Now, I want to override that in my decorator:

```
Spree::Product.class_eval do
  scope :in_sale, -> { on_hand.where(in_sale: true) }
end
```

Instead of the copied over original implementation of `.where(in_sale: true)`, I would prefer to call the original.

How can you re-use an original scope, somewhat similar to how you would normally call `alias_method_chain :foo, :feature` for instance-methods?

Comment: Hm, doesn't plain aliasing do the job?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, yes it does. It's just slightly more complicated then defining an alias on an instance-method, because of the class-eval thing. Maybe you can put this in an answer with some code so we can close this question?

Answer (score 1):

Without actually knowing what's behind the problem, I would suggest to use:

```
product.in_sale.on_hand
```

instead of patching `Spree::Product` class.

If you still require this in one method call, you can do it like this:

```
Spree::Product.class_eval do
  # alias an old method
  class <<self
    alias_method :old_in_sale, :in_sale
  end

  # reusing old method in a new one
  scope :in_sale, -> { old_in_sale.on_hand }
end
```

**Broken**

This code seemingly works:

```
Spree::Product.class_eval do
  old_in_sale = in_sale

  # reusing old method in a new one
  scope :in_sale, -> { old_in_sale.on_hand }
end
```

As @berkes notes in his comment below, it evaluates only once for `old_in_sale` and this value is being reused in the future. It still might produce correct results, but it's not guarantied.

Comment: Won't `old_in_sale = self.in_sale` trigger the actual proc, and instead have `old_in_sale` contain the list of Prodcucts, instead of a pointer to the scope?

Comment: @berkes you are right. I've updated my answer. Btw, old code still performs well in simple cases. `old_in_sale` contains `ActveRecord::Relation` which is reused on each query. It will be broken though, if what old `in_sale` returns will be different from what we get on first execution.